# I am getting an URL error in pandas when trying to read a csv file

Tags: pandas, read.csv

Getting an error with the below code:

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

filename = "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DA0101EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/Data%20files/auto.csv"

headers = ["symboling","normalized-losses","make","fuel-type","aspiration", "num-of-doors","body-style",
"drive-wheels","engine-location","wheel-base", "length","width","height","curb-weight","engine-type",
"num-of-cylinders", "engine-size","fuel-system","bore","stroke","compression-ratio","horsepower",
"peak-rpm","city-mpg","highway-mpg","price"]

df = pd.read_csv(filename, names = headers)

tried to read a csv file using an URL

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix the filename string with a raw string literal.

You can do this but putting an r (for raw string) in front (see below).  This will let you read the csv with out throwing and error.

```
filename = r"https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DA0101EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/Data%20files/auto.csv"
```